# How to sort an array in JavaScript or jQuery with multiple objects per array record

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, object

Before you may vote me down: I have checked all existing solutions around this problem but none was similar to this.

I want to sort this array alphabetically by **image.name** (JavaScript or jQuery):

```
var myArray = [{
    creator: {
      "firstname": "Sally",
      familyname: "Bloomfield"
    },
    location: {
      "lat": 12.123,
      lng: 8.846
    },
    image: {
      name: "Hello World",
      size: "50x80"
    }
  },
  {
    creator: {
      firstname: "Bob",
      familyname: "Jones"
    },
    location: {
      lat: 31.593,
      lng: 96.376
    },
    image: {
      name: "Flowerpower",
      size: "40x50"
    }
  },
  {
    creator: {
      firstname: "John",
      familyname: "Walker"
    },
    location: {
      lat: 27.184,
      lng: 123.120
    },
    image: {
      name: "Guiness",
      size: "33x66"
    }
  }
];
```

The array output after sort:

```
[{
    creator: {
      firstname: "Bob",
      familyname: "Jones"
    },
    location: {
      lat: 31.593,
      lng: 96.376
    },
    image: {
      name: "Flowerpower",
      size: "40x50"
    }
  },
  {
    creator: {
      firstname: "John",
      familyname: "Walker"
    },
    location: {
      lat: 27.184,
      lng: 123.120
    },
    image: {
      name: "Guiness",
      size: "33x66"
    }
  },
  {
    creator: {
      firstname: "Sally",
      familyname: "Bloomfield"
    },
    location: {
      lat: 12.123,
      lng: 8.846
    },
    image: {
      name: "Hello World",
      size: "50x80"
    }
  }
]
```

So first image **F**lowerpower then **G**uiness then **H**ello World.

The existing sort function of Javascript can't handle this as I have tried that out. Is it even possible to sort such structures?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can pass your own comparator to the JavaScript sort function

Comment: @Jacob: I have done that by sending "image.name" but was ignored.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Jacob: I was using the sortOn function from Bob: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects
Then I used it that way: sortOn (myArray, image.name, false, false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.image.name === b.image.name) {
        return 0;
    }
    return a.image.name < b.image.name ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: First and correct answer! Was not aware of using object access like image.name in the internal sort function.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `localeCompare` when sorting strings. Then it's just one line using `Array.sort()`:

```js
var myArray = [{creator: { "firstname": "Sally", familyname: "Bloomfield"},location: { "lat": 12.123, lng: 8.846},image: {name: "Hello World", size: "50x80"}},{creator: { firstname: "Bob", familyname: "Jones"},location: { lat: 31.593, lng: 96.376},image: {name: "Flowerpower", size: "40x50"}},{creator: { firstname: "John", familyname: "Walker"},location: { lat: 27.184, lng: 123.120},image: {name: "Guiness", size: "33x66"}}];

myArray.sort((a,b) => a.image.name.localeCompare(b.image.name))
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Thank you as well for correct solution and especially considering localeCompare! 1up!

Comment: @Jonny you should use `localeCompare` rather than the selected answer if you want to make sure names with accents continues to work. The other solutions will put a name like `émile` at the end of the list rather than with the other `e`s.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into issues because you have a typo in your array. There's a lone double quote `"` on `line 14`.

This worked for me when I removed the extra quote:

```
var myArraySorted = myArray.sort((a, b) => {
   if (a.image.name < b.image.name) {
       return -1
   }
   return 1;
});
```

Comment: `Array.sort()` sorts the original in place. You don't need to assign the result to anything.

Comment: Thank you, corrected. Was a kinda simplified array sample I put together.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for the `Array.prototype.sort()` function compare items and shift their indexes alphabetical for `type String` and numerically for `type Number`.  As you're sorting an `Object` you need to plug into the specific property you wish to target, like so...

```
function compare(a, b) {
    return a.image.name === b.image.name ? 0 :
        a.image.name < b.image.name ? -1 : 1;
}

var sorted = myArray.sort(compare);
```

Hope that helps  :D

[Array.sort @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: The problem with sorting strings this way is that it doesn't do sensible things with strings like `Elle` vs `Étienne`.